# Can individual case statements have type parameters? If so, how?

Tags: scala

I'm trying to write a function that takes a String, calls a 3rd party library twice and if the results happen to be the same type and that type is Ordered, to compare the items based on the string.  For example (that doesn't compile but hopefully conveys what I mean):

```
def libraryFunction(i: Int): AnyRef  // this is somewhere else

def comp(c: String): Boolean = {
  val aa = libraryFunction(0)
  val bb = libraryFunction(1)
  (c, aa, bb) match {
    case [A <: Ordered[A]]("<", a: A, b: A) => a < b
    case [A <: Ordered[A]](">", a: A, b: A) => a > b
    ....
  }
}
```

A naive solution would be to simply enumerate all the types I care about:

```
def comp(c: String): Boolean = {
  val aa = libraryFunction(0)
  val bb = libraryFunction(1)
  (c, aa, bb) match {
    case ("<", a: Int, b: Int) => a < b
    case (">", a: Int, b: Int) => a > b
    case ("=", a: Int, b: Int) => a == b
    case ("<", a: Double, b: Double) => a < b
    ....
  }
}
```

But that seems like a ton of redundant code (I'm using squants to track units, so there's more than just int and double to worry about) that I'd like to avoid if possible.

Is there some way to do this?  Or even a more formal way of asking the question such that searching would be more fruitful?

**Edit**: my initial attempt to hide some of the complexity seems to have been poorly executed, refactoring to expose relevant details.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make you BlackBox type parametrized.

```
  case class BlackBox[T](l: T, r: T)

  def comp[A: Ordering](c: String, d: BlackBox[A]): Boolean = (c, d) match {
    case ("<", BlackBox(a, b)) => implicitly[Ordering[A]].lt(a, b)
    case (">", BlackBox(a, b)) => implicitly[Ordering[A]].gt(a, b)
  }

  println(comp(">", BlackBox(1, 2)))
  println(comp(">", BlackBox(1.5, 2.5)))
```

I don't think that you can do it without type-parametrization. If you don't have types at compile type you have no chances to get Ordered implicit instance. Implicit resolution is compile time operation.

Comment: If it helps, the BlackBox was really a simplification for clarity of my actual problem.  In reality I'm making two calls to a function that returns an AnyRef, then I'm pattern matching on the results.

Comment: @teryret the real question is, why does the function return `AnyRef`? If you can do something about it, that's infinitely better than resolving your original problem

Comment: Agreed.  Unfortunately doing that would involve starting a major fork of Apache Storm.

Comment: I suggest you to build type facade around AnyRef. We have similar problem with Datomic (written in clojure) where almost everything AnyRef. We convert early it to types, and it makes our life much easier.